# How to send a specific url pattern to 404 in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I am generating a url, whose proper pattern is as follows:

`https://example.com/equipment_details/slug`

This is the url google is supposed to be indexing. But due to pagination implementation using javascript there is another active url on platform as follows:

`http://localhost:3000/equipment_details/slug?page=2`.

**controller** method is like below:

```
class EquipmentsController < ApplicationController
  def equipment_details
    @equipment = Equipment.friendly.active.includes(:country, :manufacturer, :category, :user).find(params[:id])
    if @equipment
      @products = @equipment.category.equipments.active.where.not("equipment.id = ?", @equipment.id)
      @countries = Country.active.all
      @states = State.active.all
      @cities = City.active.all
      @services = Service.active.where("category_id = ? AND sub_category_id = ? AND country_id = ? AND state_id = ? AND city_id = ?", @equipment.category_id, @equipment.sub_category_id, @equipment.country_id, @equipment.state_id, @equipment.city_id)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
        format.pdf do
          render :pdf => "vendaxo_#{@equipment.title}",
                 :layout => 'equipment_details_pdf.html.erb',
                 :disposition => 'attachment'
        end
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "Equipment not found."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Basically the main content on both url is same except for the javascript pagination content in the footer.  This is causing issues in SEO optimization. How can I send the url with second pattern i.e the uel with `?page=2` to `404` page ? Is there a way to do it from rails routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically want to look for a query parameter called `page` and raise an exception to activate the 404 response (if that request isn't an AJAX call from your javascript), you can do that in a before action in your `EquipmentDetailsController` (or whatever it's called).

```
class EquipmentDetailsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :send_to_404, only: [:name] # or whatever the action is called

  def send_to_404
    if !request.xhr? && !params[:page].nil?
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: Please check I added the controller method

Comment: That `name` in the url is not actually a controller method name but the `slug` from `friendly_id`

Answer (score 0):

You could send a 404 using when `params[:page] == 2`:

```
render plain: "record was not found", status: :not_found
```

However, you shouldn't simply send a 404 when you don't want Google to index the page (that actually does exist). [Google evaluates javascript these days as well](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html).

Consider adding a [noindex header to the page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en) and/or use [a canonical url reference](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#2):

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/equipment_details/name">
```